# Error 401 Unauthorized when i try to access to an API with permitAll()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I am developing a spring boot project using keycloak with the following configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurations{
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/users").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/products/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(new ConverterJwt());
        return http.build();
    }
```

```
public class ConverterJwt implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
@Value("${keycloak.client-id}")
private String client;

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(final Jwt source) {
    Map<String, Object> resourceAccess = source.getClaim("resource_access");
    Map<String, Object> resource = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.get(client);
    Collection<String> resourceRoles = (Collection<String>) resource.get("roles");
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = resourceRoles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return new JwtAuthenticationToken(source, authorities);
}
```

}

The problem is that when i try to send a request to /users from Postman I reiceve the 401 error. It seems that i don't have the authorization even if the API is accessible from anyone.

here is my configuration.yaml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EcommerceDB?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: ---
    password: ---
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8080/realms/EcommerceKeycloack/protocol/openid-connect/certs
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/realms/EcommerceKeycloak
keycloak:
  client-id: ecommerce-keycloack-client
  grant-type: authorization_code
  scope: openid


server:
  port: 8090
```

My pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.unical</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Ecommerce</name>
    <description>Ecommerce</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't send jwt token with my requests because i am tryng to test anonymous access for my API.

Comment: which version of `Spring boot` are you using?

Comment: In addition to dependencies, we are missing the `ConverterJwt` source code and properties. Without this info, all I can do is redirect you to [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials1-OAuth2-essentials)

Comment: I am using spring boot 6

Comment: If you are running an IDE with a debugger, you should be able to step through the code and see which portion is failing even if it's in framework code.

Comment: The problem is that the code works but the behavioral is strange, why I obtain error 401 in /users if in the filterChain I had used permitAll() ?.

Comment: Yes, specially if you send you request the request with a token that is not conform with what we don't see (and I requested). If you want an answer, edit your question (do not add comments) and add what I listed, plus your full configuration class (not just the security filter-chain bean)

Comment: There is some progress. Please also add your maven (or Gradle) dependencies and the JSON payload of the JWT you send with your requests (use https://jwt.io or something to get this payload, don't share signed tokens)

Comment: Hi&welcome! Please read (over) [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#use-new-requestmatchers) ... Key point: "..summary, the new methods choose the `MvcRequestMatcher` implementation if your application has Spring MVC in the classpath"..

Comment: ..so maybe `...requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**"))...` could lead to to better results

Comment: @xerx593 I tried your solution but the problem remains

Comment: What you report here should work. You have activated mothod security: maybe  is there an `@PreAuthorize` on the controller class or method your are querying? Would you add your controller source? Last step is to enable trace logging for security with `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` and report the logs for one of your queries.

Comment: I resolved the problem, apparently there was a problem with the firewall on windows.